# HBase or Hive - web requests

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, hive, bigdata

Are either HBase/Hive suitable replacements as your traditional (non)relational database? Will they be able to serve up web-requests from web clients and respond in a timely manner? Are HBase/Hive only suitable for large dataset analysis? Sorry I'm a noob at this subject. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive is not at all suitable for any real time need such as timely web responses. You can use HBase though. But don't think about either HBase or Hive as a replacement of traditional RDBMSs. Both were meant to serve different needs. If your data is not huge enough better go with a RDBMS. RDBMSs are still the best choice(if they fit into your requirements). Technically speaking, HBase is really more a `DataStore` than `DataBase` because it lacks many of the features you find in an RDBMS, such as typed columns, secondary indexes, triggers, and advanced query languages, etc.

And the most important thing which could struck a newbie is the lack of SQL support by HBase, since it belongs to NoSQL family of stores.

And HBase/Hive are not the only options to handle large datasets. You have several options like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [Hypertable](http://hypertable.org/), [MongoDB](http://hypertable.org/), [Accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org/) etc etc. But each one is meant for solving some specific problem. `For example`, MongoDB is used handling document data. So, you need to analyze your use case first and based on that you have to choose the datastore which suits your requirements.

You might find this [list](http://nosql-database.org/) useful which compares different NoSQL datastores.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Hive is data warehouse tool, and it is mainly used for batch processing.

HBase is NoSQL database which allows random access based on rowkey (primary key). It is used for transactional access. It doesn't have indexing support which could be limitation for your needs.

Thanks,
Dino